# When is a linear map conformal

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, geometry

I was trying to find out when a linear map is conformal (i.e. angle preserving) when I came across [this](http://www.cs.bsu.edu/homepages/fischer/math445/angles.pdf).

These notes state that a linear map is angle preserving if and only if it is multiplication by a constant. But although I don't see where there is any mistake in the proofs it seems clear to me that rotations (which are not multiplication by a constant) also preserve angles.

> Please could someone clarify to me when a linear map on $\mathbb R^n$
>   or $\mathbb C^n$ is conformal (=angle preserving)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$||L\mathbf v||=\lambda ||\mathbb v||$ does not mean that $L$ isn't a rotation. All it says is that every vector of unit length become length $\lambda$. It doesn't say anything about what $L$ does to the *direction* of any single vector.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know *what* I was thinking...

Answer (score 0):

At each $x $ in $\mathbf{R}^2$, $Df(x)$, i.e. the derivative of $f$ at $x$, is a matrix from $R^2$ to $C^2$. For $f$ to be conformal, at each $x$ this matrix has to be angle-preserving, thus, by the argument found in the link below, it has to be a multiple of an orthogonal matrix. But, notice that this will vary as $x$ changes.

[ALL Orthogonality preserving linear maps from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1769021/all-orthogonality-preserving-linear-maps-from-mathbb-rn-to-mathbb-rn)